# Sequelize many-to-many relationship TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have a many-to-many relationship modeled similarly to the code below. The `VendorEmployeeModel` represents a join table, but there may not always be an `Employee` record unless they sign up and link their `Employee` record to their `VendorEmployee` record (the vendor may just create a `VendorEmployee` record to keep track of what each `Employee` is currently working on). Given the `VendorEmployeeModel` represents more than just a join table I am not using the `BelongsToMany` decorator.

I am using the `BelongsTo` and `HasMany` decorators throughout the codebase without issue. The only thing that seems to be different here is a `Vendor` can have many `VendorEmployees` and a `VendorEmployee` can have many `Vendors` (think of it as a gig-economy type of scenario).

The error I'm seeing here is:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
      at Object.getForeignKeyOptions (node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/associations/foreign-key/foreign-key-service.js:24:40)
      at HasAssociation.getSequelizeOptions (node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/associations/has/has-association.js:17:52)
      at associations.forEach.association (node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize.js:49:45)
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at models.forEach.model (node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize.js:48:26)
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Sequelize.associateModels (node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize.js:44:16)
      at Sequelize.addModels (node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize.js:36:14)
      at new Sequelize (node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize.js:18:22)
      at SequelizeConnection.initialize (src/common/infrastructure/sequelize.ts:30:21)
      at DatabaseTestFrameworkSimple.<anonymous> (test/framework/database.ts:74:24)
      at test/framework/database.ts:8:71
      at Promise._execute (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:427:9)
      at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:518:18)
      at new Promise (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:103:10)
      at Object.<anonymous>.__awaiter (test/framework/database.ts:4:12)
      at DatabaseTestFrameworkSimple.initializeTestDb (test/framework/database.ts:71:16)
      at DatabaseTestFrameworkSimple.<anonymous> (test/framework/database.ts:98:16)
      at fulfilled (test/framework/database.ts:5:58)
      at tryCatcher (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
      at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
      at Promise._settlePromise (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
      at Promise._settlePromise0 (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
      at Promise._settlePromises (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
      at _drainQueueStep (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
      at _drainQueue (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
      at Async.Object.<anonymous>.Async._drainQueues (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
      at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
```

Besides that main error I'm also seeing a `SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error` and `TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined`. If I remove the `VendorEmployee` and `Vendor` `BelongsTo / HasMany` decorators then everything works fine (other the includes in my repository).

Here is the code:

```
@Table({
  tableName: 'VendorEmployee'
})
export default class VendorEmployeeModel extends Model<VendorEmployeeModel> {
  @Default(() => IdUtility.generateUid())
  @Column
  uid!: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => VendorModel)
  @Column
  vendorId!: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => VendorModel)
  vendor: VendorModel;

  @ForeignKey(() => EmployeeModel)
  @Column
  employeeId: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => EmployeeModel)
  employee: EmployeeModel;

  @IsEmail
  @Column
  email: string;

  @Column
  phone!: string;

  @Column
  firstName!: string;

  @Column
  lastName!: string;
}

@Table({
  tableName: 'Vendor'
})
export default class VendorModel extends Model<VendorModel> {
  @Unique
  @Default(() => IdUtility.generateUid())
  @Column
  uid: string;

  @HasMany(() => VendorEmployeeModel)
  vendorEmployees: VendorEmployeeModel[];
}

@Table({
  tableName: 'Employee'
})
export default class EmployeeModel extends Model<EmployeeModel> {
  @Unique
  @Default(() => IdUtility.generateUid())
  @Column
  uid: string;

  @Unique
  @Column
  userUid: string;

  @HasMany(() => VendorEmployeeModel)
  carrierDriver: VendorEmployeeModel[];
}
```

Versions:

- sequelize: ^5.17.2
- sequelize-typescript: 1.0.0
- typescript: 3.7.2